# Make ConstraitLayout that holds a Recyclerview clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

I have a RecyclerView placed within a ConstraintLayout. What I am trying to achieve is making the ConstraintLayout clickable and focusable, not the RecyclerView or it's items. Currently I  am only able to focus the area surrounding the RecyclerView-items. Any help highly appreciated!

```
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/select_background_top"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/safety_title">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/device_list"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@drawable/select_background_top"
          android:paddingVertical="@dimen/half_content_padding"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/recycler_view_arrow"
          app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          tools:itemCount="3"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
          android:id="@+id/recycler_view_arrow"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/half_content_margin"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
          app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_24dp"
          app:tint="@color/secondaryIconColor" />

      </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: while this isn't a clean solution, why can't you create another constraint layout which would go over your recycler and your constraint layout ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody Thank you for the reply. That does not work tho, the recyclerView is still being prioritized over the constraintLayout.